# Rails 4, IE11 and JS Response

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, internet-explorer-11, ujs

I am having problems with using IE11 (echh) with Rails 4 and a JS response

it doesn't work..

```
def sign_in
     # some code
   respond_to do |format|
    format.js {render partial: 'shared/login_needed'}
   end
end
```

this is the view

```
<%= link_to "GET STARTED", sign_in_path, remote: true, class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg get_started" %>
```

When clicked on the link this happens:

```
Mar 29 07:12:07 myapp app/web.1:  ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/browserconfig.xml"): 
Mar 29 07:12:07 myapp app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call' 
Mar 29 07:12:07 myapp app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call' 
Mar 29 07:12:07 myapp app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app' 
Mar 29 07:12:07 myapp app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call' 
Mar 29 07:12:07 myapp app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged' 
Mar 29 07:12:07 myapp app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged' 
Mar 29 07:12:07 myapp app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged' 
Mar 29 07:12:07 myapp app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call' 
Mar 29 07:12:07 myapp app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call' 
Mar 29 07:12:07 myapp app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call' 
Mar 29 07:12:07 myapp app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call' 
Mar 29 07:12:07 myapp app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call' 
Mar 29 07:12:07 myapp app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call' 
Mar 29 07:12:07 myapp app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call' 
Mar 29 07:12:07 myapp app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call' 
Mar 29 07:12:07 myapp app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call' 
Mar 29 07:12:07 myapp app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call' 
Mar 29 07:12:07 myapp app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/connection.rb:86:in `block in pre_process' 
Mar 29 07:12:07 myapp app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `catch' 
Mar 29 07:12:07 myapp app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `pre_process' 
Mar 29 07:12:07 myapp app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process' 
Mar 29 07:12:07 myapp app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data' 
Mar 29 07:12:07 myapp app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine' 
Mar 29 07:12:07 myapp app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run' 
Mar 29 07:12:07 myapp app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start' 
Mar 29 07:12:07 myapp app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start' 
Mar 29 07:12:07 myapp app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:16:in `run' 
Mar 29 07:12:07 myapp app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start' 
Mar 29 07:12:07 myapp app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:84:in `start' 
Mar 29 07:12:07 myapp app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>' 
Mar 29 07:12:07 myapp app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap' 
Mar 29 07:12:07 myapp app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>' 
Mar 29 07:12:07 myapp app/web.1:    bin/rails:4:in `require' 
Mar 29 07:12:07 myapp app/web.1:    bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

**Update**

I've added

```
  <meta name="msapplication-config" content="none"/>
```

and the above routing error is gone. But IE11 still doesn't do anything when clicked on the link

There are not js errors, these are the headers for the response

```
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:text/javascript; charset=utf-8
Expires:-1
Pragma:no-cache
Server:thin 1.6.2 codename Doc Brown
transfer-encoding:chunked
Vary:Accept
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
X-Request-Id:a4cdc500-d720-4156-b61c-7a5ae427d430
X-Runtime:0.007740
X-Ua-Compatible:chrome=1
X-Xss-Protection:1; mode=block
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How about showing the js-console in your browser? Maybe you have syntax errors. On chrome osx: alt + cmd + j

Comment: @Nick have you found the answer?

Comment: Six years later and I'm here having the same problem too. Any Clue? I cannot even simulate it...